# How to print ng-template index?

Tags: html, angular6

> I want to print the index of the container
>
> i tried to write `{{index}}` but it isnt working

```
<ng-template #stepsClone  >
          <p>Paragraph {{index}} </p>
          <input type="button" (click)="removeStep(index)" value="X" >
        </ng-template>
```

```
export class AddInterviewComponent {

  @ViewChild('stepsClone') template;

  @ViewChild('stepsContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  cloneStep() {
    this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
  }
  removeStep(index: any) {
    this.container.remove(this.template[index]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your component you declare

```
index = 'test';
```

please post your components.ts file

Comment: i want the index of the container

Comment: could you please explain little bit more about your requirement and code

Answer (score 0):

Try this to show your template:

```
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-template>
```